# To call Java Script in a webpage using external VB script (IE automation)

Tags: javascript, vbscript, automation, ui-automation, browser-automation

There is a check box in a webpage upon clicking it, it will select all the check box beneath it . It works by calling a java script function (on click) .

When i check that particular check box using VB script by .getElementById("").checked=True, Only that particular check box is selected and all other check box beneath it is not checked.

The reason is because when i using getElementID, only particular checkbox is selected and Java script function is not executed.

May i know how to call that function/ any other ways to select all the checkboxes?

Note: I don't have access to change the html contents of that webpage.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be anything stopping you from calling the JavaScript function from VBScript.

```
<script language="vbscript" type="text/vbscript">
    Function TestVBS()
        MsgBox "In TestVBS"
        testJS   ' Now call a JavaScript function from VBScript
    End Function
</script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function testJS() {
        alert("In testJS");
    }
</script>

<input type="button" language="vbscript" onclick="TestVBS" value="Click Me" />
```

Comment: The Javascript function will not be in my code snippet. I am trying to call js function available in the webpage using vbs IE automation. Pls correct me if i am wrong.